Finding Second Derivative using implicit differentiation and the product rule
Problem:
Find $y''$ given:
$$  x + xy + y = 2 $$
Answer:
\begin{align*}
x + x \dfrac{dy}{dx} + y + \dfrac{dy}{dx} &= 0 \\
(x+1) \dfrac{dy}{dx} + x + y &= 0 \\
(x+1) \dfrac{dy}{dx}  &= -x - y  \,\,\,\,\,\, \text{eq 1} \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}  &= \dfrac{  -x - y  }{x+1 } \\
\end{align*}
Now, I go back to eq 1 and differentiate again.
\begin{align*}
(x+1) \dfrac{ d^2y}{dx^2} + \dfrac{dy}{dx} &= -1 - \dfrac{dy}{dx} \\
(x+1) \dfrac{ d^2y}{dx^2}  &= -1 - 2\dfrac{dy}{dx} \\
(x+1) \dfrac{ d^2y}{dx^2}  &= -1 + \dfrac{ 2(x+y) } { x+ 1 } \\
(x+1) \dfrac{ d^2y}{dx^2}  &= \dfrac{ 2(x+y) - x - 1 } { x+ 1 } \\
(x+1) \dfrac{ d^2y}{dx^2}  &= \dfrac{ x  + 2y - 1 } { x+ 1 } \\
\dfrac{ d^2y}{dx^2}  &= \dfrac{x  + 2y - 1 }{(x+1)^2}
\end{align*}
However, the book's answer is:
$$ y'' = \dfrac{ 2(1+y) }{(1+x)^2} $$
Where did I go wrong?

Second line should be $1 + x \dfrac{dy}{dx} + y + \dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$ (I checked until first error).

About error I wrote in comment.
Accordingly to title if/when you would like to use derivative of implicit function, then taking $F(x,y)= x + xy + y - 2$ we obtain
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{F_x}{F_y}=-\frac{1+y}{1+x}$$
For second derivative
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = - \frac{\frac{dy}{dx}(1+x)-(1+y)}{(1+x)^2}=\frac{ 2(1+y) }{(1+x)^2}$$

Here's a non-standard answer since your equation has such nice symmetry. First of all notice that
$$
xy + x + y + 1 = 1, 
$$
or in other words,
$$
(x+1)(y+1) = 1. 
\tag{1}
$$
This suggests that we should shift the coordinates by defining
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned} 
u &= x + 1 \\
v &= y + 1 
\end{aligned} 
\right.
$$
so the Equation (1) is just
$$
uv = 1.
\tag{2}
$$
What about derivatives? By the chain rule
$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u} 
= \cancel{\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}y}} \cdot 
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \cdot 
\cancel{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}u}} 
= \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}. 
$$
Similarly, for second derivatives,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 v}{\mathrm{d}u^2} 
= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} u} 
\biggl[ \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u} \biggr]
= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} 
\biggl[ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \biggr] \cdot
\cancel{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}u}}
= \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} 
$$
All of this is to say that we can just work with $u$ and $v$ and sub $x$ and $y$ back in at the end! Differentiating Equation (2) with respect to $u$ yields
$$
u\,\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u} + v
= 0, 
\tag{3}
$$
or
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u} = - \frac{v}{u}.
$$
Notice that this is the same as writing in the original variables
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = - \frac{y+1}{x+1}.
$$
Let's differentiate Equation (3) again with respect to $u$:
$$
\biggl( u\,\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 v}{\mathrm{d}u^2} 
+ \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u} \biggr) 
+ \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u} 
= 0, 
$$
or
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 v}{\mathrm{d}u^2} 
= -\frac{2}{u}\, \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u} 
= -\frac{2}{u} \biggl(\! -\frac{v}{u} \biggr)
= \frac{2v}{u^2}.
$$
This last equation in the original variables is
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} 
= \frac{2(y+1)}{(x+1)^2}, 
$$
as expected.

Note that taking the derivative (with respect to $x$) once leads to the equation $$1+xy'+y+y'=0,\text{ i.e., }y'=-\frac{1+y}{1+x}.$$ Now one takes the derivative again to obtain $$y''=\frac{1+y-y'(x+1)}{(1+x)^2}.$$ Plug in the value of $y'$ from above to get $y''=\frac{2(1+y)}{(1+x)^2}.$

The method of implicit differentiation is of course perfectly viable, but not required. In the present case we can avoid the method by rewriting the relation between $y$ and $x$ as:
$$y = \frac {2-x} {1+x} = -1 + \frac {3}{1+x}$$
We then obtain directly $$y' = -\frac {3} {(1+x)^2}$$
and $$y'' = \frac {6} {(1+x)^3}$$
The result for $y''$ can be rewritten in terms of $y$ and $y'$. For example $y'' = \frac{2(1+y)}{(1+x)^2} = -\frac {2y'}{1+x}$.
